# List cuts end with new line

Tags: html, css

Every time my list goes to a new line of code, I end up having the end of the background & border cut off for some odd reason.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTpKx.png]

```css
li.list {
    display: inline;
    line-height: 30px;
    width: inherit;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    color: #8e8d8d;
    background-color: rgba(204,204,204,0.5);
    margin: 5px; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC; border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
}
```

```html
<li class="list"><span>Timmy Smith&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="delete-button">&times;</span></span></li>
```

Everything works fine on the individual li, but when the list needs to jump to the next line in order to fit the width of the container, it cuts off the end of the li.

What am I doing wrong??

Edit: As requested, here is a jsfiddle as well. 
http://jsfiddle.net/DannLea/t6gxg29o/

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle?

Comment: I cant reproduce it, do you have an example of really not working code? JSFiddle or other?

Comment: are you wrapping your li's in a ul/ol? it's likely that the container is cutting them off. wrapping them and adding proper margin to the container should fix the issue.

Comment: @ackerman second line is also wrapping (on example image), it does not look as container problem

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DannLea/t6gxg29o/
There's a fiddle. You may need to resize to see problem.

Comment: looks OK on Firefox, is broken in Chrome - is browser specific

Comment: Confirmed **working** in Internet Explorer. Ah, Chrome, how I love you. Your desire to take shortcuts in order to be the "fastest" browser has once again led you into trouble.

Comment: Noted for both browsers, thanks to each areim and Neit the Dark Absol for the cross browser testing. Was able to test on Firefox and confirmed the problem only persists on Safari and Chrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `display: inline-block` instead of `display:inline`

working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/t6gxg29o/1/)

It breaks margins, but this you can fix easily.

Otherwise, using padding and margins on `inline` elements does not work.

Comment: Can't - That separates each li to a new line. But for the record, it does fix the issue of cutting the end off.

Comment: How is this separation possible? It works in JSFiddle, you gave me.You have some different conditions?

Comment: For some reason in my css, this pushes each element to a new line and stretches to 100%. Please note I am using bootstrap

Comment: I can't reproduce this "new" problem (tested on FF, Chrome - Linux), you have `width: inherit;` in your code, try to change it to `width: auto;`. But I'm only guessing...

Comment: Solved!
For the record, changing the width to auto was necessary as well.
Thanks so much!